# How to JUnit test a iterator

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

For example, how do I test:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.iterator();
```

How to test this "`iterator()`" method?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to test `iterator()`?

Comment: i wrote my own iterator for one of my class and I want to test everything about that iterator (probably next(), hasNext()...empty case stuff)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The few tests I can think of are:

- test hasNext on an empty collection (returns false)
- test next() on an empty collection (throws exception)
- test hasNext on a collection with one item (returns true, several times)
- test hasNext/next on a collection with one item: hasNext returns true, next returns the item, hasNext returns false, twice
- test remove on that collection: check size is 0 after
- test remove again: exception
- final test with a collection with several items, make sure the iterator goes through each item, in the correct order (if there is one)
- remove all elements from the collection: collection is now empty

You can also have a look at [the tests used in openJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/test/java/util/Collection/IteratorAtEnd.java).

Comment: to add to this comprehensive response. another test can be: checking exception like  `ConcurrentModificationException`  when elements of list are changed concurrently while iterator iterate on the list.